# Doctrine2: how to get one of the inversed side entities with ManyToOne relationship for a given id

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-1.2

I've two doctrine entities with ManyToOne relationship:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Iballot\CmsBundle\Entity\PollingStation2", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 * @Expose
 */
private $pollingStation2;
```

and I'd like get a specific one result for a given PollingStation2 ID and I've try that but doesn't work:

```
public function getPresidential($polId)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
    $qb->where('r.pollingStation2 = :polling_station2_id')
       ->setParameter('polling_station2_id', $polId);

    return $qb->getQuery()
               ->getResult();
}
```

Entities

```
namespace Iballot\CmsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * PollingStation2
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Iballot\CmsBundle\Entity\PollingStation2Repository")
 */
class PollingStation2
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="verfierNumber", type="integer", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $verfierNumber;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="verifier_number", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $verifierNumber;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $address;


    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Iballot\CmsBundle\Entity\PollingStation2", mappedBy="pollingStation")
    */
    protected $result;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Iballot\CmsBundle\Entity\Constituency", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    */
    private $constituency;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->getName();
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return PollingStation2
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set address
     *
     * @param string $address
     *
     * @return PollingStation2
     */
    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get address
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * Set verifierNumber
     *
     * @param integer $verifierNumber
     *
     * @return PollingStation2
     */
    public function setVerifierNumber($verifierNumber)
    {
        $this->verifierNumber = $verifierNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get verifierNumber
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getVerifierNumber()
    {
        return $this->verifierNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set verfierNumber
     *
     * @param integer $verfierNumber
     *
     * @return PollingStation2
     */
    public function setVerfierNumber($verfierNumber)
    {
        $this->verfierNumber = $verfierNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get verfierNumber
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getVerfierNumber()
    {
        return $this->verfierNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set constituency
     *
     * @param \Iballot\CmsBundle\Entity\Constituency $constituency
     *
     * @return PollingStation2
     */
    public function setConstituency(\Iballot\CmsBundle\Entity\Constituency $constituency)
    {
        $this->constituency = $constituency;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Get constituency
     *
     * @return \Iballot\CmsBundle\Entity\Constituency
     */
    public function getConstituency()
    {
        return $this->constituency;
    }



    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->result = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add result
     *
     * @param \Iballot\CmsBundle\Entity\PollingStation2 $result
     *
     * @return PollingStation2
     */
    public function addResult(\Iballot\CmsBundle\Entity\PollingStation2 $result)
    {
        $this->result[] = $result;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove result
     *
     * @param \Iballot\CmsBundle\Entity\PollingStation2 $result
     */
    public function removeResult(\Iballot\CmsBundle\Entity\PollingStation2 $result)
    {
        $this->result->removeElement($result);
    }

    /**
     * Get result
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getResult()
    {
        return $this->result;
    }
}
```

Comment: May we see the both entities?

Comment: of course please see it again

Comment: your relation seems not to be bi-directionnal. What is the mapping you wish? $result --n:1--> $pollingStation2 ?

Comment: I want to get one result for a given pollingStation ID. and notice that I didn't want to use the bedirectional relationship but I just started to implete it when you aske me to post...

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. What is the second entity?

Comment: I couldn't post but my problem is simple: 1- for non bedirectional relationship ManyToOne can you show an exemple of a method that can help me to get one entity of the inversed side ? example (my case) many Results can be connected to one pollingStation then if I want to get a result (inversed side) for a given pollingStation Id what would be my repository method ?

Comment: Your repository method seems to be good but your mapping don't allowed it.

Comment: First, did you try `app/console doctrine:schema:validate` ?

Comment: after running the command i've got: database [ok] Mapping [ok]

Comment: You have a mappedBy pollingStation but the target entity has pollingStation2?  Also, verify that your database has the correct id relation values.  I suspect you may have some null id's.